# When is it true that $(y_1-x_1)^p + (y_2 -x_2)^p \leq (y_2 - x_1)^p + (y_1 - x_2)^p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Consider four integers $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ with $x_2 > x_1$ and $y_2 > y_1$.  Is it true that the only integer values of $p$ so that:

$$(y_1-x_1)^p + (y_2 -x_2)^p \leq (y_2 - x_1)^p + (y_1 - x_2)^p$$

are $p=0, 1$ and all even $p \geq 2$?

Comment: how do you define $(-1)^{1.5}$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks. I have fixed the question.

Comment: It’s true for $p=2$ as well.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Thank you. Is it true for any other integers $p$?

Comment: Just play a around with some intergers and make a guess.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I added my guess.